# Creating Event Receiver Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2013

I am going through Beginning Sharpoint 2013 Development and I need to create an event reciever. I don't have a local copy of SharePoint on my laptop I'm using a development site from an Office 365 installation. How can I create an event listner when I get the below error message when trying to open and empty project in VS 2013? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to develop SharePoint solutions (farm or sandboxed), you must have SharePoint server installed. You can develop SharePoint apps without SharePoint Server, but you may need the Office Developer Tools, depending on your version of Visual Studio (the latest version of 2013 may have them installed already).

Office 365 does not support solutions that use managed code (no-code sandboxed solutions are still supported).  The new [app model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164084%28v=office.15%29.aspx) should be used instead.

This means that instead of using an Event Receiver, you should use a [Remote Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456315%28v=office.15%29.aspx).